# Bayesian Linear Regression to assess looking time behavior

Tags: regression, bayesian

I study perceptual development in infancy and recently came across an interesting article using Bayesian linear regression to identify phoneme discrimination in individual infants.

Let me set the stage first. These researchers used a habituation/discrimination procedure, which examines novelty response by way of looking time. In other words, when working with infants, a robust way to examine whether or not they noticed a change in a stimulus is whether or not their attention spiked in response to a new object when shown on a computer. 
Made up data:

Trial 1 - 10s looking time to a ball

Trial 2 - 8s looking time to a ball

Trial 3 - 6s looking time to a ball

Trial 4 - 3s looking time to a ball

Trial 5 - 9s looking time to a star

From the made up example above, this is the looking time spike I'm talking about,i.e. the child noticed the change from ball to star. Normally these types of procedures are used with groups of infants, not individuals.

To make a long story short, the authors in the paper listed at the end of the post used Bayesian linear regression to examine if individual infants exhibited response recovery to the novel trials in a 12 trial test period where 4 of the trials were novel. I've only used linear models and a few robust models, so I have no idea how this was done. Can anyone explain this to me? I've looked at the bayesm and WinBugs packages in R, but am having trouble figuring out how to apply this technique if I wanted to do it myself. Thanks in advance for any input.

Article: Assessing speech perception in children with cochlear implants using a modified hybrid visual habituation procedure. By Cynthia Core, Janean Brown, Michael Larsen, and James Mahshie (2014)

Comment: Have you tried contacting the authors? They should be willing to share their code with a fellow researcher who wants to replicate their approach.

Comment: Hi David,
I have tried contacting the authors but have not heard back.

Comment: That's a shame! http://reproducibleresearch.net

Comment: If you could find an open-access article in this field that does some *explicit theorizing about the mechanisms underlying* such looking-time behavior, I'd be glad to sketch a JAGS model for you to illustrate how you could begin. What I'm looking for is a sense of how you and others in your field conceive of the 'data generating process' (DGP). A key ingredient of your 'conceptions' will be the *constructs* (latent variables) you imagine beneath the surface, determining the observables.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the previous post by the way, it looks like a website that more researcher should utilize and I possibly could once I have some data.
It's tough to find an open-access article that describes the method in full. I can email you an article if you would like?
In short, this methodology investigates infants' sensitivity to change detection as a function of looking time. The procedure consists of two phases, a habituation phase and a test phase. The habituation phase displays some stimulus typically on a computer) to the infant over and over until they are "bored" of it, ...

Comment: to the point where their attention has dropped by 50% (typically on the last 3 trials compared to the first 3 trials). One this occurs the testing phase begins. During the test phase infants are shown a novel trial or trials with the rationale being if their looking time exhibits response recovery, they successfully "noticed" the stimulus changed. Just as if adults see the same thing over and over they get bored, then if something new pops up we are more interested. This is a classic way to investigate infants' sensitivity to change to a wide range of stimuli (faces, speech, etc).

Comment: Not sure if that helps? As for defining these behavioral characteristics in terms of latent variables, the field is not good at that. If I had to conceptualize it, I would say the latent variable being examined is 'novelty seeking behavior'.